# Include another HTML file in a HTML file in the HEAD section of the document

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

There are plenty of examples of how to included content from one html file in another, including this:

[Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)

Is it possible to include content from an other file in the HEAD of the calling html document?

**If I try this:**

**Source**

```
<html>

    <head>
        <div id="headerInclude"></div>
        <script src="/lforms-examples/lib/jquery-1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>$("#headerInclude").load("/lforms-examples/pages/header-footer/ComponentHeader.html");</script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Basic Questionnaire Example Using Header</h1>
    </body>

</html>
```

**Include**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/lforms-examples/img/nachc-favico.png">
    </head>
</html>
```

**I get this:**

Note the link is in the body and not the head and the favicon.ico is not found.
[image]

Comment: Include when? At server response time, or only after the client starts loading the page? Because the first is trivial: use any of many available templating engines, and the second is "stop and start doing the first instead".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$.get` from jQuery to add data to head tag. After inital page render.

```
$.get('./lforms-examples/pages/header-footer/ComponentHeader.html', function(data) {
    $('head').append(data);
});
```

Read more about favicon
https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/rel-shortcut-icon